# Missing WSDL Operations when importing EWS WSDL into SOAP UI Project

Tags: xsd, soapui, exchangewebservices

I need to create a Mock Service for EWS and I have gotten hold of the WSDL file and .XSD from the Exchange server endpoint (I am logged with my credentials)

- https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Services.wsdl
- https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Messages.xsd
- https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Types.xsd

I have created a project in SOAP UI and when I generated a Mock Service only the following WSDL operations's responses are mocked:

- AddDelegate
- AddDistributionGroupToImList
- AddImContactToGroup
- AddImGroup
- AddNewImContactToGroup
- AddNewTelUriContactToGroup
- AddTag

At a closer look and testing the validity of the WSDL as well as the .XSDs, the following errors are highlighted:

**Services.wsdl:** "

> Referenced file contains errors (file:/pathToFile/types.xsd).

I then look at the error in types.xsd and it seems to point to the attribute in:

```
<xs:complexType name="ReplyBody">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Message" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

with the following error message (I am validating within Eclipse Neon):

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'ReplyBody' is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs     too often.
>     - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xml:lang' to a(n) 'attribute declaration' component.

I have tried to remove that attribute, but the issue remains. Am I missing anything obvious?

Can you please help?

Thanks,

I.

**EDIT 1**
My main concern is that I am possibly going completely wrong in the way I am getting hold of the EWS WSDL and schemas. Is that the right way to do it?

**EDIT 2**
I have also try to import the WSDL directly from the URL and I am returned with the same missing operations.

Comment: I believe that you may have the privilege to modify the xsd either, right? May be you may want to go the wsdl provider and report it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I can modify the xsd files, but I am not sure where the problem lays and I am interested to hear whether other people came across the same issue

Comment: I have ended up adding manually each of the operations I was interested in and generating the mock responses.

Comment: It is easy to mock using soap ui

Comment: This is what I did from the very beginning, but when creating the MockService, not all operations were mocked. I have had to do it manually for those missing and not happy about it - particularly because I am not sure why that happened.